# What's topology of $L^p$ when p is smaller than 1?

Tags: functional-analysis

For $p>1$ or $p=1$, $L^p(X,\Sigma,m)$ space is a normed vector space with $L^p$ norm. However, when $p<1$, if $f\in L^p$, $$||f||_{L^p}=(\int_X |f|^p dm)^{1/p} $$ fails to be a norm. So my question is whether the collection of sets $B(f,\epsilon)=\{g\in L^p| ||f-g||_{L^p}<\epsilon\}$ for $\epsilon>0$ and any $f\in L^p$ forms a base when $0<p<1$ for some topology?

Comment: that collection generates a locally convex topological vector space

Comment: @mathworker21: it's a TVS, but not locally convex

Comment: @Dap yea, you're right. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, this defines a **topological vector space**, but not locally convex, as noted in the comments. First note that it is complete and metrizable, namely by
$$d(f,g) = \int_X |f-g|^p \, \mathop{dm},$$
since it satisfies the $\Delta$-inequality,
because $|x-y|^p \leq |x-z|^p + |z-y|^p$ if $0 < p <1$.

> One interesting fact is that the continuous dual space $(L^p[a,b])^*$ is trival, i.e. consists only of the zero-functional.

Proof: Let $F \in (L^p[a,b])^*$. Assume that there exists $f \in L^p[a,b]$ with $F(f) \neq 0$. By Rescaling we can assume that $F(f)=1$. Now by continuity of the measure (and since $\lambda$ is non-atomic), we may decompose $[a,b] = \cup_{i=1}^n [a_i,b_i]$ such that $$\int_{a_i}^{b_i} |f|^p \mathop{dx} = \frac{1}{n} \int_0^1 |f|^p \mathop{dx}.$$
Now $$1= F(f) = \sum_{i=1}^n F(1_{[a_i,b_i]} f)$$
Thus, there exists $i=1,\ldots,n$ with
$$\frac{1}{n} \leq F(1_{[a_i,b_i]} f).$$
Define $g_n = n 1_{[a_i,b_i]} f$, then
$$F(g_n) \geq 1,$$
but
$$\int_0^1 |g_n|^p \mathop{dx} = n^{1/p-1} \int_0^1 |f|^p \mathop{dx} \rightarrow 0.$$
A contradction.

More information can be found [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/lpspace.pdf).

Comment: It's certainly not locally convex! Indeed, if it were, by Hahn-Banach it'd have lots of functionals, etc.